# Acting on firebase cloud function error in app

Tags: swift, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

Working with Swift, Firebase and Stripe.

I have my cloud code set up to charge customers on stipe through their Stripe Card ID.

The node.js function that performs this is (I think I got this from example code):

```
    exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onWrite(event => {
      const val = event.data.val();
      if (val === null || val.id || val.error) return null;
      return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.val();
      }).then(customer => {
        const amount = val.amount;
        const idempotency_key = event.params.id;
        let charge = {amount, currency, customer};
        if (val.source !== null) charge.source = val.source;
        return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key});
      }).then(response => {
          return event.data.adminRef.set(response);
        }, error => {
          return event.data.adminRef.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error)).then(() => {
            return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
          });
        }
      );
    });
```

Everything works well in the function but I'm looking to deal with a case where the customer invokes this function but either their card is no longer active/removed/for some reason an error occurs.

Is there a way to get some sort of return from the cloud to the app that I can use to perform an alert..etc or is the only way to set up an observer on a certain value and have the cloud function change/have stripe webhook ping cloud and then change that value in the case where an error occurs?